# LISP Easy questio about creating new lists

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

A function that receives a list with sublist's M*N and returns the sum of all elements of the sublist's

example: `(solution '( (1 2 3) (4 5 6) ) )`

return: `(5 7 9)`

Sry for the bad english
thks =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Common Lisp version is almost the same as in Scheme:

```
(defun solution (list)
  (apply #'mapcar #'+ list))

(solution '((1 2 3) (9 10 11) (3 4 5)))
; ==> (13 16 19)
```

Comment: @LuísTiago: You have successfully broken almost every guideline regarding asking questions on this site and you still have been given a good answer. At least have the decency to accept it and give the answerer the credit they have earned. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what Lisp interpreter you're using. In Scheme, this will work:

```
(define (solution lsts)
  (apply map + lsts))
```

For example:

```
(solution '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
=> '(5 7 9)
```

Comment: i'm using LispWorks and that doesn't work. It must be somenthing like (defun solution (lista) ...